# How do I stop receiving hashtags as links from Twitter?

Tags: html, twitter, hyperlink, telegram, hashtag

I wanted a Twitter forwarder to Telegram.

I found this one: https://github.com/franciscod/telegram-twitter-forwarder-bot

The problem is now, that if a tweet contains a hashtag before a link, Telegram show me the link to the hashtag.

[image]

I tried different things and searched about that, but I don't know how to only receive plain text from twitter.

Also I don't get the short link t.co if the tweet is to long. It's just a long link.

```
for tweet in tweets:
    self.logger.debug("- Got tweet: {}".format(tweet.text))

    # Check if tweet contains media, else check if it contains a link to an image
    extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')
    pattern = '[(%s)]$' % ')('.join(extensions)
    photo_url = ''
    tweet_text = html.unescape(tweet.text)
    if 'media' in tweet.entities:
        photo_url = tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url_https']
    else:
        for url_entity in tweet.entities['urls']:
            expanded_url = url_entity['expanded_url']
            if re.search(pattern, expanded_url):
                photo_url = expanded_url
                break
    if photo_url:
        self.logger.debug("- - Found media URL in tweet: " + photo_url)

    for url_entity in tweet.entities['urls']:
        expanded_url = url_entity['expanded_url']
        indices = url_entity['indices']
        display_url = tweet.text[indices[0]:indices[1]]
        tweet_text = tweet_text.replace(display_url, expanded_url)

    tw_data = {
        'tw_id': tweet.id,
        'text': tweet_text,
        'created_at': tweet.created_at,
        'twitter_user': tw_user,
        'photo_url': photo_url,
    }
    try:
        t = Tweet.get(Tweet.tw_id == tweet.id)
        self.logger.warning("Got duplicated tw_id on this tweet:")
        self.logger.warning(str(tw_data))
    except Tweet.DoesNotExist:
        tweet_rows.append(tw_data)

    if len(tweet_rows) >= self.TWEET_BATCH_INSERT_COUNT:
        Tweet.insert_many(tweet_rows).execute()
        tweet_rows = []
```

Comment: 1. Post code. 2. post expected and actual output

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EpIG2

Comment: @mplungjan https://pastebin.com/scDBzEUR

Answer (score 0):

Just disable [markdown_twitter_hashtags()](https://github.com/franciscod/telegram-twitter-forwarder-bot/blob/master/util.py#L33) function, make it return `text` without replace that.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Looked at the wrong place the whole time.

Comment: Ok. Everything works now. I just deleted the expanded_ at expanded_url. Thank you.