# Filter tweets with keywords

Tags: python, twitter, filter, telegram

I'm using the Twitter Forwarder Bot (prev. asked about something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366980/how-do-i-stop-receiving-hashtags-as-links-from-twitter)).
I looked at the code, where I could implement an if condition to filter words and hashtags, but I don't know what to do.
I think Job.py looks like the right place for it, but I'm not sure.

[GitHub Adress for the original files.](https://github.com/franciscod/telegram-twitter-forwarder-bot)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need filtered tweets out of the context, you can go for [twitteR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9) library on R's

```
searchTwitter(search_string, no of tweets,...)
```